# Scroll-Based Animation

Tags: jquery

I wanted to create another setup of Scroll-Based Animation but this time, when the container appeared on your screen it will execute the code inside "once" only.

I would like to use jQuery setup only, no CSS3.

Here's the code that I am using from SitePoint.

```
var $animation_elements = $('.programs');
var $window = $(window);

function check_if_in_view() {
  var window_height = $window.height();
  var window_top_position = $window.scrollTop();
  var window_bottom_position = (window_top_position + window_height);

  $.each($animation_elements, function() {
    var $element = $(this);
    var element_height = $element.outerHeight();
    var element_top_position = $element.offset().top;
    var element_bottom_position = (element_top_position + element_height);

    //check to see if this current container is within viewport
    if ((element_bottom_position >= window_top_position) && (element_top_position <= window_bottom_position)) {
      $element.addClass('in-view');

      var AK1 = new CountUp("countUp1", 0, 12, 0, 2.5, options),
          AK2 = new CountUp("countUp2", 0, 1, 0, 2.5, options),
          AK3 = new CountUp("countUp3", 0, 53451, 0, 2.5, options);

      AK1.start();
      AK2.start();
      AK3.start();

    } else {
      $element.removeClass('in-view');
    }
  });
}

$window.on('scroll resize', check_if_in_view);
$window.trigger('scroll');
```

[SitePoint Scroll-Based Animations jQuery/CSS3](https://www.sitepoint.com/scroll-based-animations-jquery-css3/)

The `var` that you can see inside there is the *CountUpJS, and wanted to start animate it once the container appear on the browser.

[CountUpJS](https://inorganik.github.io/countUp.js/)

**NOTE**

Here's the updated JSFiddle sample of the code.
Again, whenever you scroll, animation of the counter keeps repeating. What i wanted to achieve here it to scroll down, and animate the counter one time only (even if i scroll up and down).

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/imarkdesigns/0kut2jh2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're adding the `in-view` class only when you have detected that the item is in view, perhaps you can just add another class as a flag to "remember" if an item has been animated before? Example:

```
//check to see if this current container is within viewport
if ((element_bottom_position >= window_top_position) && (element_top_position <= window_bottom_position) && !$element.hasClass('has-been-in-view')) {
  $element.addClass('in-view');
  $element.addClass('has-been-in-view');

  var AK1 = new CountUp("countUp1", 0, 12, 0, 2.5, options),
      AK2 = new CountUp("countUp2", 0, 1, 0, 2.5, options),
      AK3 = new CountUp("countUp3", 0, 53451, 0, 2.5, options);

  AK1.start();
  AK2.start();
  AK3.start();

} else {
  $element.removeClass('in-view');
}
```

Comment: yeah, it was working fine, however the CountUpJS script keeps repeating whenever i scroll on visible container... maybe because of the `$.each()`. is there alternative way for that? i wanted only to animate the Counter once the container appear on the screen.

Comment: you can check my jsfiddle for reference.

Comment: I've just updated your JSFiddle with my little code example and it seems to be working OK. Check the `if` statement and the `.addClass(...)` line that have been changed/added.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be doing this with documentready?

$window.on('scroll resize', check_if_in_view);

not sure if above code actually works though

Comment: the given code was working fine.. however, everytime i scroll over the visible container, it keeps repeating the animation of CountUpJS.

Comment: you can check my jsfiddle above for reference.